# the limit of a impropre integral

Tags: real-analysis

I would like to ask you a question about the limit of an improper integral:

How fast the following integral goes to infinity as $a \searrow 0$?
$$I(a):= \int_0^{1}\dfrac{f(E_0+t^2)dt}{t^2-a^2}$$
where $E_0$ is fixed and $f$ is an analytic function near $E_0$.